# Unable to access a dynamically generated dropdownlist item. It comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, kendo-ui

I am working on a webpage which has a tabstrip depending on number of people in a deal. As it can be 1 for one deal and 3 for another, I have created the drop down items dynamically using a loop index.

```
<tr>
        <td align="right">
             <spring:messagecode="label.borrower.employer.status" />:
        </td>
        <td align="right">
             <kendo:dropDownList name="employmentStatus${requestScope.loopIndex}"
                dataTextField="text" dataValueField="value" style="width: 100%;"
                select="employmentStatusOnClick(${requestScope.loopIndex})" 
                change="updateEmploymentInfo">
                       <kendo:dataSource data="${borrowerEmploymentStatus}"></kendo:dataSource>
            </kendo:dropDownList>
       </td>
```

I am able to see the drop down lists according to the number of people in a deal. However, this jsp is included in another main jsp and the "change" and "select" functions are in that main jsp. When a value is selected on a drop down, I want to capture it and then perform some operations.

```
<script>
function employmentStatusOnClick(index) {
    console.log(exp.loopCounter);
    console.log("counter: "+index);

    var employmentStatusVal = $("#employmentStatus"+index).data(
            "kendoDropDownList").text();

    console.log(employmentStatusVal);
}
</script>
```

For output, I can see that the value of index is coming correctly. However, even before the page is fully loaded, i get the error that "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined**"

**Things I have Tried So far:** 
1) Tried to add the script inside ready() function, but it then gives me an error that employmentStatusOnClick is not defined

2) Tried different variations of concatenating the index value with the base name of the drop down list

3) Tried passing the value into a variable and then putting it into the .text() function

4) Latest, I have even tried hardcoding the value of index as 0 to see if it works for the first case, but i still get the undefined error.

I suspect that it has to do something with the loading of the elements. For some reason, it is trying to run this code, even before the element name has been generated. I discussed with a friend and he suggested me to remove the select events and just use the change event instead. Tried that..no effect.

Now, I am planning to remove kendo drop-downs and just use javascript dropdowns as a last resort. Can you please suggest what could be the problem?

**Update - HTML Code of the div from Browser:**

```
<div id="tab-employment">
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Employer Name</th>
                    <th>Occupation</th>
                    <th>Employment Status</th>
                    <th>Hiring Date</th>
                </tr>

                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>Roagres</td>
                        <td>Assistant</td>
                        <td>Current</td>
                        <td>2018-03-12 11:59:06.0</td>
                    </tr>

            </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1%"></td>
        <td>
            <table style="display: inline-block;">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td align="right">Employment Status:</td>
                    <td align="right"><input name="employmentStatus0" style="width: 100%;" id="employmentStatus0"><script>jQuery(function(){jQuery("#employmentStatus0").kendoDropDownList({"dataTextField":"text","dataValueField":"value","change":employmentStatusOnClick(0),"dataSource":{"data":[{"text":"--Select--","value":"--Select--"},{"text":"Employed","value":"Employed"},{"text":"Self-Employed","value":"Self-Employed"},{"text":"Retired","value":"Retired"},{"text":"Seasonal","value":"Seasonal"},{"text":"Student","value":"Student"},{"text":"Unemployed","value":"Unemployed"},{"text":"TEST","value":"TEST"}]}});})</script></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Industry Sector:</td>
                    <td align="right"><input name="industryStatus" style="width: 100%;" id="industryStatus"><script>jQuery(function(){jQuery("#industryStatus").kendoDropDownList({"dataTextField":"text","dataValueField":"value","change":industryStatusOnClick,"value":"1","dataSource":{"data":[{"text":"--Select--","value":"8443"},{"text":"Agriculture/Fishing/Forestry/Mining","value":"8444"},{"text":"Food/Foodservice/Hospitality","value":"8445"},{"text":"Arts/Entertainment/Recreation/Sports","value":"8446"},{"text":"Insurance, Accounting and Banking","value":"8447"},{"text":"Design/Creative","value":"8448"},{"text":"Construction & Skilled Trades","value":"8449"},{"text":"Education and Training","value":"8450"},{"text":"Government/Public Administration","value":"8451"},{"text":"Engineering/Architecture","value":"8452"},{"text":"Manufacturing/Production/Operation","value":"8453"},{"text":"Medical and Healthcare","value":"8454"},{"text":"Media/Telecommunication/Communication","value":"8455"},{"text":"Religion","value":"8456"},{"text":"Legal Services","value":"8457"},{"text":"Emergency and Protection","value":"8458"},{"text":"Real Estate","value":"8459"},{"text":"Professional, Scientific, and Technical Services","value":"8460"},{"text":"Information Technology","value":"8461"},{"text":"Transportation and Utilities","value":"8462"},{"text":"Sales/Marketing/Retail","value":"8463"}]}});})</script></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Express Occupation:</td>
                    <td align="right"><input name="expressOccupation" style="width: 100%;" id="expressOccupation"><script>jQuery(function(){jQuery("#expressOccupation").kendoDropDownList({"dataTextField":"text","dataValueField":"value","change":expressOccupationOnClick,"value":"1"});})</script></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Other - Specify:</td>
                    <td align="right"><input type="text" id="otherSpecify" name="otherSpecify" disabled="disabled" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div id="empStatusMsg" style="margin: 0 0 0 0; color: red; width: 300px; float: right;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML the browser receives?

Comment: @OscarPaz I have added the HTML code from the browser for this div. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, finally I was able to figure this out. Seems like the issue was with the kendo tag libraries or atleast my implementation of them. Before the page was even loaded, the change event was being fired up.

Therefore, I removed the change event from the kendo tag definition and rather used the jquery on change event nested inside document.ready(). After this it started working fine.